# Battery supervisor circuit question

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, lipo

I am working on a digital watch just for fun and learning. It is powered with a small "3.7 V" LiPo and the 3.3 volts for the primary circuit will be supplied from "3.3v Voltage Regulator". I would like to use something like a "MAX6461 Voltage Detector" to sense when the LiPo gets low. My question is if it is appropriate to use the output from the 6461 to control the regulator "shutdown" input directly. Reducing size and parts count is critical for me, so this seems like an efficient route. I am aware that this would still drain the battery with he quiescent current of these ICs, but since it's a watch, the user will notice that it is no longer functioning long before the quiescent current draw causes damage. Otherwise maybe I need to consider more conventional circuits with a full shutoff transistors to disconnect the battery.

Voltage Regulator was edited to reflect a comment that was made below.

Comment: Silly question, but does the lipo have a BMS in it alread?

Comment: Most do, however I want to keep options open for coin cells, and/or cheap overseas cells where I may not trust the onboard BMS.

Comment: MAX1724 is a boost converter, it will not provide 3.3V from 3.7V battery